# Angular + Dynamic meta tags

Tags: javascript, angular, meta-tags, social-media

I am using Angular4, and have an app that can display images:

example of (fake) urls:

- https://example.com/images/table
- https://example.com/images/chair etc

When loading one of those URLs:

1. The website gets downloaded
2. The app (angular) boots
3. It issues a few queries to the backend, and after 1 or 2 seconds, angular receives the information about the image:

   - `images/table` will display `https://path/to/table123.jpg`
     or
   - `images/chair` will display `https://path/to/chairABC.png`
4. I then update the meta tag via a call to `setMetadata(...)` in the head and **correctly shows** as:
   `<meta property="og:image" content="https://path/to/table123.jpg">` so the update of the meta tags works

So far, so good.
The problem is that when sharing a link to either facebook or google plus, such as `https://example.com/images/table`, **the preview image is not correct, it does not pick up the updated meta tags**.

Using https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ also shows the same problem : it does not display the tags updated by Angular, only the original tags.

How can that be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and Google are looking for the data when the page is first loaded and they aren't going to wait around while your app looks for the information and updates the page.

You'll need to either create static pages that you can share to (these would have the images already in them) that will redirect back to the real page or you'll need to use Angular Universal to implement Server Side Rendering